# PHP rename files, starting with special name?

Tags: php, regex, printf, scanf

i wanted to rename files from databse. so..i wrote bellow.
**it works fine except for names with long length int.**
(ex: `bartmp_9404865346.jpg` does not work but `bartmp_585558.jpg` is working)

```
$subject = '[img]http://www.example.org/users/uploads/bartmp_9404865346.jpg[/img]
            Hello world
            [img]http://www.example.org/users/uploads/bartmp_585558.jpg[/img]';

preg_match_all('/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/', $subject, $files);


foreach ($files[1] as $file) {
  $n = sscanf($file, "http://www.example.org/users/uploads/bartmp_%d.jpg");
  $refile = sprintf("http://www.example.org/users/uploads/mybar_%d.jpg", $n[0]);
  rename($file, $refile);
}
```

can you give me any alter way to do this or a little hint to modify this.
thanks.

Comment: use %f float instead of %d integer

Comment: @TamilSelvan   i Dont think it is ok, because it will return something like "myanswerlk_9404865346.000000.jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `%d` for decimal which seems superficially correct:

```
$n = sscanf($file, "http://www.example.org/users/uploads/bartmp_%d.jpg");
$refile = sprintf("http://www.example.org/users/uploads/mybar_%d.jpg", $n[0]);
```

The issue is the max numerical value in PHP—and other languages compiled as 32-bit—is `2147483647` so `9404865346` won’t fly. Instead you should look to extract the value as a string instead like this:

```
$n = sscanf($file, "http://www.example.org/users/uploads/bartmp_%s.jpg");
$refile = sprintf("http://www.example.org/users/uploads/mybar_%s", $n[0]);
```

Comment: `%s` matches non-digits too, not sure that was intended (regardless of the acceptance of this answer).

Comment: Hey, my cat uses `prey_match()` too ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The `%d` format specifier only accepts numbers that would fit in an integer (depending on the platform that would be 2^31 or 2^63); without losing precision, in this case, a regular expression may work better:

```
if (preg_match('#^http://www.example.org/users/uploads/bartmp_(\d+)\.jpg$#', $file, $matches)) {
    $refile = sprintf('http://www.example.org/users/uploads/mybar_%s.jpg', $matches[1]);
    rename($file, $refile);
}
```

The above expression matches only digits but stores the match as a string value, so it won't lose numeric precision.

Comment: so ```%d``` has a limit(?), interesting. My $0.02 - what about casting the long int into to string and handling as such? Might not be the 100 best... Thx/good work.

Comment: @datamafia Yeah, depending on the platform it would be 2^31 or 2^63 :)

Comment: "depending on the platform" < super helpful, never went that far and god to know.

Comment: double Mersenne prime, thx for the insight. Good answer nonetheless.